# mail-sor-xxx.google.com fails DKIM / SPF check

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I got a DMARC report for my domain as `xyz.xml` where it showed me domains & their corresponding checks (either SPF / DKIM) that failed. My problem is I have one entry as follows:

```
<source_ip></source_ip>
  <count>1</count>
  <policy_evaluated>
    <disposition>none</disposition>
    <dkim>pass</dkim>
    <spf>fail</spf>
```

**209.85.220.41** points to `mail-sor-xxx.google.com` .

My SPF & DKIM :

`"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"`

`"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=xfdf+sadasfsa+sacsc+""`

Why doe DKIM pass & SPF fail ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You may want to add a bit more of information from the DMARC xml to your question. Usually this involves a different return-path than your own domain or forwarding (or both). The auth_results section should contain the info I'd be looking for.

Comment: Sorry for giving out incomplete info .Here's my [Dmarc xml](https://file.io/engMW7) .

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, and saw this thread, says "Safe to ignore it"

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/19303899?hl=en